# Is there any way to improve my AES encryption code in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, aes

I have this code for AES encryption, can some one verify that this code is good and not wrong? It works fine, but I'm more concerned about the implementation of the algorithm.

```
// Plaintext value to be encrypted.

//Passphrase from which a pseudo-random password will be derived.
//The derived password will be used to generate the encryption key.

//Password can be any string. In this example we assume that this passphrase is an ASCII string.

//Salt value used along with passphrase to generate password.
//Salt can be any string. In this example we assume that salt is an ASCII string.

//HashAlgorithm used to generate password. Allowed values are: "MD5" and "SHA1".
//SHA1 hashes are a bit slower, but more secure than MD5 hashes.

//PasswordIterations used to generate password. One or two iterations should be enough.

//InitialVector (or IV). This value is required to encrypt the first block of plaintext data.
//For RijndaelManaged class IV must be exactly 16 ASCII characters long.

//KeySize. Allowed values are: 128, 192, and 256.
//Longer keys are more secure than shorter keys.

//Encrypted value formatted as a base64-encoded string.


public static string Encrypt(string PlainText, string Password, string Salt, string HashAlgorithm, int PasswordIterations, string InitialVector, int KeySize)
{
    byte[] InitialVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(InitialVector);
    byte[] SaltValueBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Salt);
    byte[] PlainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PlainText);
    PasswordDeriveBytes DerivedPassword = new PasswordDeriveBytes(Password, SaltValueBytes, HashAlgorithm, PasswordIterations);
    byte[] KeyBytes = DerivedPassword.GetBytes(KeySize / 8);
    RijndaelManaged SymmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
    SymmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    ICryptoTransform Encryptor = SymmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(KeyBytes, InitialVectorBytes);
    MemoryStream MemStream = new MemoryStream();
    CryptoStream CryptoStream = new CryptoStream(MemStream, Encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    CryptoStream.Write(PlainTextBytes, 0, PlainTextBytes.Length);
    CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
    byte[] CipherTextBytes = MemStream.ToArray();
    MemStream.Close();
    CryptoStream.Close();
    return Convert.ToBase64String(CipherTextBytes);
}

public static string Decrypt(string CipherText, string Password, string Salt, string HashAlgorithm, int PasswordIterations, string InitialVector, int KeySize)
{
    byte[] InitialVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(InitialVector);
    byte[] SaltValueBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Salt);
    byte[] CipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(CipherText);
    PasswordDeriveBytes DerivedPassword = new PasswordDeriveBytes(Password, SaltValueBytes, HashAlgorithm, PasswordIterations);
    byte[] KeyBytes = DerivedPassword.GetBytes(KeySize / 8);
    RijndaelManaged SymmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
    SymmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    ICryptoTransform Decryptor = SymmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(KeyBytes, InitialVectorBytes);
    MemoryStream MemStream = new MemoryStream(CipherTextBytes);
    CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(MemStream, Decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
    byte[] PlainTextBytes = new byte[CipherTextBytes.Length];
    int ByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(PlainTextBytes, 0, PlainTextBytes.Length);
    MemStream.Close();
    cryptoStream.Close();
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(PlainTextBytes, 0, ByteCount);
}
```

i'm not a pro security guy or a pro programmer, I start learning and I love to understand it

my plans is to build an AES encryption functions that requires minimal inputs yet a following standards so it will be easy to make an equivalent functions in another languages like PHP and JavaScript!

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some general comments. The first is around the IV. In general, you want the IV to be random. By restricting it to (displayable) ASCII, you're somewhat limiting the possible values. In general, you'd be better off by a) using the GenerateIV() method, and b) prepending the IV value to the ciphertext, so that c) you don't need to pass it as a parameter to either function.

The second comment is that, in general, you need to plan for future changes to your crypto needs. It would be better to embed some versioning or parameter information alongside the ciphertext, and avoid embedding specific crypto settings in your code. If, at a later date, you decide to double the number of iterations for the password, for instance, you might still want to decrypt values that were encrypted using the older settings (or warn the user that the value is no longer accessible).

You can also push a lot of decisions into your config files. For instance, you can [create a name for your crypto](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff3k1hh4.aspx) provider (e.g. MyAppSymmetricCrypto) that maps to RijndaelManaged today, but at a later date, could be changed to whatever is then appropriate.

Comment: And the comments about the IV also hold for the Salt.

Answer (score 2):

In addidtion to @Damien_The_Unbeliever answer

MS recommends using `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` instead of `PasswordDeriveBytes`. (and then you can drop 'HashAlgorithm' from your method parameters).

You can calculate the IV from your password:

```
var bytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, iterations);
var key = bytes.GetBytes(keySize);
var iv = bytes.GetBytes(ivSize);
```

you should check your input values for invalid values/ranges.

Wrap the `MemoryStream` & `CryptoStream` classes in `using` statements.

Comment: I personally wouldn't recommend using the same IV for multiple messages, even if the same password is being used for both. Same IV + Same key reveals if two messages start with the same (N = block size) bytes. This may or may not be a meaningful disclosure, but for a general crypto solution should be avoided.

Comment: I mean var iv = bytes.GetBytes(ivSize); "iv" is it the "InitialVectorBytes" in my code? and what is "ivSize" where it is in my code?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever , Thanks allot, again not sure how I can implement your suggestion!